# How to parse image from Feedburner RSS feed in Android

Tags: android, xml, rss, feed

I am trying to get the **media:thumbnail** or **media:content** from Reuters Top News feed (http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews). But the feed is generated by Feedburner, and the there is no media:content or media:thumbnail tags. There are a lot of img src information from the  tag, but strangely these images are empty (highlighted in the XML below).

Here is the item XML I got from the Reuters feed:

```
<item><title>U.S. banks seen falling short of new debt funding rule</title><link>http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/reuters/topNews/~3/M_C5zQtGkmM/story01.htm</link><description>WASHINGTON (Reuters) - Wells Fargo, State Street and JPMorgan Chase &amp; Co are below or almost at minimum capital thresholds expected to be included in a rule still being hammered out by U.S. regulators that's meant to mitigate taxpayer losses in another financial crisis, according to a Reuters analysis.&lt;img width='1' height='1' src='**http://reuters.us.feedsportal.com/c/35217/f/654200/s/3b92de13/sc/1/mf.gif**' border='0'/&gt;&lt;br clear='all'/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/rc/1/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="**http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/rc/1/rc.img**" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/rc/2/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/rc/2/rc.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/rc/3/rc.htm" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/rc/3/rc.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/a2.htm"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/a2.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/199119768574/u/49/f/654200/c/35217/s/3b92de13/sc/1/a2t.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
&lt;a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/reuters/topNews?a=M_C5zQtGkmM:4K39DmkD6Z4:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/reuters/topNews?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/reuters/topNews?a=M_C5zQtGkmM:4K39DmkD6Z4:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/reuters/topNews?i=M_C5zQtGkmM:4K39DmkD6Z4:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://feeds.reuters.com/~ff/reuters/topNews?a=M_C5zQtGkmM:4K39DmkD6Z4:-BTjWOF_DHI"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/reuters/topNews?i=M_C5zQtGkmM:4K39DmkD6Z4:-BTjWOF_DHI" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/reuters/topNews/~4/M_C5zQtGkmM" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description><category domain="">topNews</category><pubDate>Tue, 17 Jun 2014 05:39:07 GMT</pubDate><guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/06/17/us-usa-banks-debt-analysis-idUSKBN0ES0C620140617?feedType=RSS&amp;feedName=topNews</guid><feedburner:origLink>http://reuters.us.feedsportal.com/c/35217/f/654200/s/3b92de13/sc/1/l/0L0Sreuters0N0Carticle0C20A140C0A60C170Cus0Eusa0Ebanks0Edebt0Eanalysis0EidUSKBN0AES0AC620A140A6170DfeedType0FRSS0GfeedName0FtopNews/story01.htm</feedburner:origLink></item>
```

Here is the screenshot of Pulse app for the same feed. But they are able to pull image from the feed. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwoi20ljgsign7s/Screenshot_2014-06-17-09-57-05.png)

So my question is how the Pulse News gets the image from particular feeds?

Thanks!

Comment: It's likely that the get it from the HTML document itself...

Comment: @JulienGenestoux, yes, but i was wondering why these image src provided in the description are all empty. i copy and paste the url to the browser, and can't get any meaningful image for the feed. Just wondering how apps like Pulse news extract image from the feed.